# Ambushed by ts-node Error: Unknown File Extension?

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, tsconfig, ts-node

I was working on a microservice using Typescript, Docker, K8s, and skaffold perfectly fine for weeks!

All of a sudden i received this error while running the app.

````
```skaffold dev```

```shell
Listing files to watch...
 - asg4/tickets
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Watching for changes...
[tickets] 
[tickets] > tickets@1.0.0 start
[tickets] > ts-node src/index.ts
[tickets]
[tickets] TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /app/src/index.ts
[tickets]     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
[tickets]     at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:99:9)
[tickets]     at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:139:38)
[tickets]     at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:83:20)
[tickets]     at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:781:28)
[tickets]     at load (/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/child/child-loader.js:19:122)
[tickets]     at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:781:28)
[tickets]     at Hooks.load (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:381:26)
[tickets]     at MessagePort.handleMessage (node:internal/modules/esm/worker:153:24)
[tickets]     at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:761:20) {
[tickets]   code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
[tickets] }
[tickets] 
Cleaning up...
 - ingress.networking.k8s.io "ingress-service" deleted
```
````

I singled out one of the services (as this issue affected all my other services as well) and tried to isolate the problem, coming to understand it was an issue with interacting  ESM modules and CommonJs files. Each of the scripts below in my package.json are all the attempts I made without success.

Just to clarify, running the app after compiling shown in the first 3 scripts (clean, build, start) WORKS (does not use ts-node but just tsc cli). Yet *none* of solutions provided online have solved this suddenly occurring issue that has rendered my ts-node useless and causing some esm module confusion/issues.

I also have tried:

(1) installing typescript, ts-node, etc... globally...

(2) ...then removing them,

(3) updating typescript, ts-node, etc... locally,

(4) configuring tsconfig.json a variety of different ways,

(5) renaming exports to match placement of compiled runs (exports:./index.js vs exports:./build/index.js, etc...),

but to no avail have I been able to restore ts-node functionality without invoking this error. I AM using ESM module btw and need the package.json to indicate "type":"module" for the sake of import/export usage. I am currently trying to debug within vsCode, but have not successfully launched one.

#### Local Ticket Service Run: Basic ts-node -> Error

````
```shell
> tickets@1.0.0 start2

> ts-node src/index.ts

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\services\tickets\src\index.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:99:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:139:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:83:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:781:28)
    at load (C:\services\tickets\node_modules\ts-node\dist\child\child-loader.js:19:122)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:781:28)
    at Hooks.load (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:381:26)
    at MessagePort.handleMessage (node:internal/modules/esm/worker:153:24)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:761:20) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```
````

#### package.json

````
```json
{
  "name": "tickets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": "./build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "del /q /s build",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc",
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "start2": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "start3": "ts-node-esm --require ts-node/register src/index.ts",
    "start4": "node --trace-warnings --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts",
    "start5": "node --loader=ts-node/esm --require ts-node/register src/index.ts",
    "start6": "nodemon src/index.ts",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/test/setupTests.ts"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@amansg4/microservices-shared": "^1.1.26",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dependencies": "^0.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "joi": "^17.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.3",
    "mongoose-update-if-current": "^1.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "nats": "^2.12.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.54.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.54.1",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "mongodb-memory-server": "^8.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "prettier": "2.8.4",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 16.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 7.11.0"
  }
}

```
````

#### tsconfig.json

````
```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "ES2022"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    //"declaration": true,
    //"declarationMap": true,
    //"listFiles": true,
    //"sourceMap": true,
    //"allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.jsx"
  ],
  //"exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  }
}
```
````

#### Verifying presence of tsConfig

````
```ts-node --showConfig```

```shell
{
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",
    "cwd": "C:\\services\\tickets",
    "projectSearchDir": "C:\\services\\tickets",
    "project": "C:/services/tickets/tsconfig.json"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "es2022"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./.ts-node",
    "strict": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noEmit": false
  }
}
```
````

#### Global Veriables (when installed)

````
```npm ls -g```

```shell
C:\AppData\Roaming\npm
├── @types/node@18.16.0
├── ts-node-dev@2.0.0
├── ts-node@10.9.1
├── tslib@2.5.0
└── typescript@5.0.4
```
````

#### Infinite errors when tying to use loader to preload esm module

````
```npm run start4 ```

```shell
> tickets@1.0.0 start4
> node --trace-warnings --loader=ts-node/esm src/index.ts

(node:41516) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
    at emitExperimentalWarning (node:internal/util:273:11)
    at createModuleLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:418:9)
    at loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:18:19)
    at runMainESM (node:internal/modules/run_main:53:21)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:5)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
(node:41516) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
    at emitExperimentalWarning (node:internal/util:273:11)
    at createModuleLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:418:9)
    at Object.get esmLoader [as esmLoader] (node:internal/process/esm_loader:15:26)
    at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:119:47
    at node:internal/util:764:15
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:26)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\services\tickets\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:7:1)
(node:41516) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
    at emitExperimentalWarning (node:internal/util:273:11)
    at createModuleLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:418:9)
    at Object.get esmLoader [as esmLoader] (node:internal/process/esm_loader:15:26)
    at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:119:47
    at node:internal/util:764:15
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:26)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\services\tickets\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:7:1)

    //Keeps repeating aka stuck in infinite loop
```
````

`npm run start5`

````
```shell

> tickets@1.0.0 start5
> node --loader=ts-node/esm --require ts-node/register src/index.ts

(node:41992) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:41992) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:41992) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:41992) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:41992) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time

                 //Keeps repeating aka stuck in infinite loop

```
````

## Thanks for any help!